# Response Validation with Match Each

Tags: karate

Appreciate any help in advance, I'm trying to match each 'userCanDismiss' value below however with how I have it scripted it passes regardless of if the value is true or false. The response below is only to show what level of the JSON I'm trying to validate down to.

```
match each response.data.validationResults[*] contains { userCanDismiss: false }

{
  "data": {
    "validationEventResults": {  
      "validationEventResults": [  
        {  
          "validationProblemStats": [  
            {  
              "occurrences": 0,  
              "problemId": "ba1a1a1d-2a35-2422-e053-0c80640a5d52"  
            }  
          ],  
          "validationId": "56034bde-1426-e785-e053-9242640a70e9",  
          "validationEventStats": {  
            "totalNumberOfProblems": 16  
          },  
          "validationResults": [  
            {  
              "id": "c9640a49-62ef-1bb6-e053-2b66680a8fc5",  
              "validationResultAdditionalDetails": [  
                {  
                  "resource": {  
                    "name": "Group Number",  
                    "oid": "7085026199"  
                  },  
                  "value": "7085026199",  
                  "key": "carrierIdentId"  
                }  
              ],  
              "problemId": "5c970f01-81ac-efaf-e053-9142640a1cf3",  
              "additionalDetails": true,  
              "userCanDismiss": true  
            },
```

Comment: Sorry Peter, the code I have is client proprietary I thought by looking at the match line you would be able to see if that is the right way I should be drilling down into the response. Not trying to waste others time.

Comment: see my answer. you made me type a few extra `}` and `]` characters and it is not easy.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just provide a hint. Sometimes you just need to use the double-dot way to get stuff out from deeply nested JSON.

```
* match each response..userCanDismiss == true
```

And also note how you can experiment by doing `def foo = {}` without needing to make any HTTP call.

Try this example below, it works. And please try to create similar well-formed examples in the future:

```
* def response =
"""
{
  "data": {
    "validationEventResults": {  
      "validationEventResults": [  
        {  
          "validationProblemStats": [  
            {  
              "occurrences": 0,  
              "problemId": "ba1a1a1d-2a35-2422-e053-0c80640a5d52"  
            }  
          ],  
          "validationId": "56034bde-1426-e785-e053-9242640a70e9",  
          "validationEventStats": {  
            "totalNumberOfProblems": 16  
          },  
          "validationResults": [  
            {  
              "id": "c9640a49-62ef-1bb6-e053-2b66680a8fc5",  
              "validationResultAdditionalDetails": [  
                {  
                  "resource": {  
                    "name": "Group Number",  
                    "oid": "7085026199"  
                  },  
                  "value": "7085026199",  
                  "key": "carrierIdentId"  
                }  
              ],  
              "problemId": "5c970f01-81ac-efaf-e053-9142640a1cf3",  
              "additionalDetails": true,  
              "userCanDismiss": true  
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
"""
* def canDismiss = $response..userCanDismiss
* match each canDismiss == true
```