# How to get all the value of specific key from from arrays of array when availability of array is dynamic

Tags: karate

I need to get all the values from following path of given json and store in another array:
Json path : $.modelGroups[] > subModelGroups[] > modelTemplates[] > id

I want to store all the Ids from modelTemplates array in another array to use it further in the code.

```
{
  "financialAssessmentId": 2,
  "modelGroups": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Revenue",
      "description": "Revenue",
      "displayOrder": 1,
      "defaultEscalationRate": 0.00,
      "subModelGroups": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Residential Revenue",
          "description": "Residential Revenue",
          "displayOrder": 1,
          "modelTemplates": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "Revenue Model Mix",
              "description": "Enter your Tenure Type Mix in % format.",
              "displayOrder": 1
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "name": "Revenue Cashflow",
              "description": "Enter your Value & Timing Inputs to calculate your Residential Cashflow.",
              "displayOrder": 2
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "Other Revenue",
          "description": "Other Revenue",
          "displayOrder": 2,
          "modelTemplates": [
            
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Cost",
      "description": "Cost",
      "displayOrder": 2,
      "defaultEscalationRate": 0.00,
      "subModelGroups": [
        {
          "id": 5,
          "name": "Operating Cost",
          "description": "Operating Cost",
          "displayOrder": 1,
          "modelTemplates": [
            
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 6,
          "name": "Development Cost",
          "description": "Development Cost",
          "displayOrder": 2,
          "modelTemplates": [
            
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 7,
          "name": "Land & Infrastructure Cost",
          "description": "Land & Infrastructure Cost",
          "displayOrder": 3,
          "modelTemplates": [
            
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Can some tell me the approach which I can follow to achieve the same?

Comment: Read this answer or simplify your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68777486/143475 - and please don't force others to read your large payloads, create an example that is small but just enough to explain: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi Peter thanks for the comment. 

Let me simplify my in question :
There are multiple "id" available in the json response. I need all the ids stored in a separate array which are present in "modelTemplates" array. Path that key is "$.modelGroups[] > subModelGroups[] > modelTemplates[] > id"

Comment: use json-path. read the linked answer and read the documentation. ask a new question if you are still stuck, but try to apply the feedback I gave above